# How best can I recreate an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, ddl

Oracle 11gR2 (x86 Windows):

I have a db with 250 tables with indexes and constraints. I need to re-create these tables, indexes and constraints in a new db and load the data. I need to know how to do the following in SQL Plus and/or SQL Developer, unless there's a magical utility that can automate all of this. Thanks in advance!

1. Unload (export) all the data from the 250 tables.
2. Create an sql script file containing the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the 250 tables.
3. Create an sql script file containing the `CREATE INDEX` statements for the 250 tables.
4. Create an sql script file containing the `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT` statements for the 250 tables.
5. Run the script to create the tables in a new db.
6. Load the exported data into the tables in the new db.
7. Run the script to create all the indexes.
8. Run the script to add all the contraints.

EDIT: I'm connected to the remote desktop which links to the source db on a Windows Server 2008. The remote only has an Oracle client installed. For security reasons, I'm not allowed to link directly from my local computer to the Win Server, so can I dump the whole source db to the remote then zip it to my local target machine? I'm trying to replicate the entire db on my computer.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from Oracle 10g, you could use the [Data Pump command-line clients](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL801) `expdb`  and `impdb`  to export/import data and/or schema from one DB to an other. As a matter of fact, those two command-line utilities are only wrappers that *"use the procedures provided in the DBMS_DATAPUMP PL/SQL package to execute export and import commands, using the parameters entered at the command line."* <sub>(quoted from Oracle's documentation)</sub>

Given your needs, you will have to create a directory then generate a full dump of your database using `expdb`:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY dump_dir AS '/path/to/dump/folder/';
```

```
sh$ expdp system@db10g full=Y directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=db.dmp logfile=db.log
```

As the dump is written using some binary format, you will have to use the corresponding import utility to (re)import your DB. Basically replacing `expdb` by `impdb` in the above command:

```
sh$ impdp system@db10g full=Y directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=db.dmp logfile=db.log
```

---

For simple table dump, use that version instead:

```
sh$ expdp sylvain@db10g tables=DEPT,EMP directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=db.dmp logfile=db.log
```

As you noticed, you can use it with your standard user account, provided you have access to the given directory (`GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY dump_dir TO sylvain;`).

---

For detailed usage explanations, see

- http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php.

Comment: One more factor: The source db is on a remote system and I need to re-create that db on my local machine. Can I just save the entire \oradata folder in dropbox and replace my \oradata with it?

Comment: @Frank Just moving the `/oradata` folder? I can't say, I've never done that. But if you have access to that folder, you still could dump your DB in there using `expdb` and copy only the dump file to your system in order ot re-import using `impdb`. _Feel_ safer to me.

Comment: I just used Oracle Data Modeler's "Generate DDL" option for creating separate sql script files for creating the tables, indexes and PK/FK constraints. The only problem is it created separate script files for each table instead of one script file for all the create tables, one script file for creating all the indexes, and one scipt file for all the constraints :( I'm working on Winx64, so guess I can concatenate the files into one.

Comment: FYI, both source and target db's are on Windows platforms, so aside from using backslashes for the directory path, I'm assuming the expdp/impdb commands in your unix shell examples remain the same for DOS cmd shell?.. I tried using the datapump in the browser-based database control utility, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Frank With the few changes you suggested, this should work on Windows too. Those are "standard" Oracle utilities. Depending your Oracle installation, _maybe_ you would need to give the full path of `impdb`/`expdb`. But beside that, all should work "out of the box". The one thing that could create difficulties is if you don't have access to the `SYSTEM` account as those two commands require full privileges on the database.

Comment: Correct, I don't have access to SYSTEM account. I tried expdb with my user account and said I didn't have permission, but can get the DBA to do it. However, I already recreated the db structure on my local machine. All I need now is to import the data. Will SQL*Loader do the trick without requiring SYSTEM or should I have DBA dump just the data with expdb?

Comment: @Frank You should definitively study the doc of `expdb`. It can do whatever you want. For a simple table(s) dump, I think you don't need advanced permissions -- and your user account _might_ suffice.

Answer (score 2):

If you can create a database link from your local database to the one that currently contains the data, you can use the `DBMS_DATAPUMP` package to copy the entire schema. This is an interface to Datapump (as @Sylvain Leroux mentioned) that is callable from within the database.

```
DECLARE
   dph NUMBER;
   source_schema VARCHAR2 (30) := 'SCHEMA_TO_EXPORT';
   target_schema VARCHAR2 (30) := 'SCHEMA_TO_IMPORT';
   job_name VARCHAR2 (30) := UPPER ('IMPORT_' || target_schema);
   p_parallel NUMBER := 3;
   v_start TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
   v_state VARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
   dph :=
      DBMS_DATAPUMP.open ('IMPORT',
                          'SCHEMA',
                          'DB_LINK_NAME',
                          job_name);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('dph = ' || dph);
   DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_filter (dph,
                                  'SCHEMA_LIST',
                                  '''' || source_schema || '''');
   DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_remap (dph,
                                 'REMAP_SCHEMA',
                                 source_schema,
                                 target_schema);
   DBMS_DATAPUMP.set_parameter (dph, 'TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION', 'REPLACE');
   DBMS_DATAPUMP.set_parallel (dph, p_parallel);
   DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job (dph);
   DBMS_DATAPUMP.wait_for_job (dph, v_state);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Export/Import time: ' || (SYSTIMESTAMP - v_start));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Final state: ' || v_state);
END;
```

The script above actually copies and renames the schema. If you want to keep the same schema name, I believe you'd just remove the `metadata_remap` call.

Answer (score -2):

SQL Developer can help with #1 by creating `INSERT` statements with a [formatted query result](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/):

```
Select /*insert*/ * 
from My_Table;
```

Comment: I don't know what database this works for, but it's certainly not Oracle.

Comment: @Allan It's a feature specific to SQL Developer, one of the tools mentioned in the question.  It's a neat feature, although I doubt it works as well as data pump, and it only addresses one of the issues.